# Visual Studio 2017 Invisible Breakpoints on the Breakpoint Bar

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

My Visualstudio 2017 Breakpoints are invisible, which means they appear in the submenu.

My application stops by hitting each breakpoint correctly.

I'm able to set and delete Brakpoints via the sidebar next to the line bar.

Breakpoints can be controlled by rightclick them and the submenü will open

BUT:

They wont appear. Setting a breakpoint in the bar only left a grey bar behind as there is no breakpoint.

So far I tried:

1. Reinstall vs 2017 7 times
2. Deinstalling all plugins and similar stuff (visual assist, Qt etc.)
3. Delete every project
4. Delete every %appdata% stuff
5. Delete registry data for vs
6. Tryed (I hope) everything in Debug config and vs settings
7. Installed it on my laptop using also intel Windows 10 etc. (there it   workes, but I still need it on my pc)

[image: Example of my problem]

[image: Breakpoint context menu]

Comment: Hi, please close VS and try to delete the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx(it is a random number) and restart VS to check. Meanwhile, make sure this option Tools → Options → Text Editor → General ---> Indicator Margin is checked.

Comment: I've done this and checked the Indicator Margin (it was and still is set). Sadly it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Does this works fine before, right? Please have a try with: 1. Go to Toos-Import and Export settings-Reset all settings and choose 'General' to restore 2. run vs with safe mode: devenv /safemode 3. perform a clean boot: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows and start Vs to check

Comment: I'm not sure about this "fine" - on my Laptop I see the breakpoints on my pc i don't. I've done all steps you mentioned (+deinstalling my anti avira) but non of it worked. I do not know where visual studio gets the breakpoints, maybe the symbol doesn't exists on my pc. All in all I'm very confused whats wrong with my pc.

Comment: Update: I set up a Virtuell Machine (Win10) and installed VisualStudio on my PC and testes Breakpoints and this worked. So it's no hardware problem. Any Idea whats wrong with my real Win10 /  VisualStudio or whatever?

Comment: As I wondered where my Icons come from, I searched trough my folders and found an ImageLibrary.cache in Appdata/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/[Number]/ImageLibrary . Because I'm totaly out of cache files I want to ask if this file could make problems in any way or show me where my Icons come from. I also found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 where is a link to an Icon file which includes the Breakpoint Icon.

Comment: Thank you for your detail information, do you remember, after your first VS installation on your PC, the breakpoints icon display or not?

Comment: I have to be thankfull for new ideas and help. And I'm not completely sure and can't remember, but would say yes I had breakpoints. But why they shoul disappear.

Comment: I tried deleting the cache file and reastart the application but still missing breakpoints.

Comment: As I deinstallnealy evergy part of VS I now think its not Vs Problem or a deep VS Problem. I removed registry/folders(also hidden folders) neraly everything including vs or VisualStudio. Some more Information i run vs 15.9.7 and I'm system admin so i've got all permissions.

Comment: And I got one more very Intresting point. I installed VS 2017 and the are Invisible, the same with the vs2019 experimental Version. I also tryed vs2015 and voila it works. So now I'm totaly confused, whats wrong with my pc ore visual Studio.

Comment: Hi ElHubert, thanks for your detail information, please go to your laptop, Tools-Import and Export settings..., export the settings and copy to the PC, then import this shared settings to have a try.

Comment: Sara Liu - MSFT I#ve done this, but sadly this change nothing.

Comment: Hi, it seems you have three breakpoints in the current TestProject.cpp, please go to DEBUG-Delete all breakpoints and just add one breakpoint to debug it again. Meanwhile, I tried to follow your example to test it in my side, it seems like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFNDwuJCteVtJlEw, did you just directly debug it after you add the breakpoints, could you please share the detail steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: 1. Open a new Project with visualc++ consolapplication. 2. Copy the linte (HelloWorld) two times and and Numbers. 3. NOW: Set some breakpoints, that won't appear (this is the Problem) (4. Press F5 (or your Run key) and run in Debug mode. Breakpoints got hit and the application stops/hold there.) Thas it simlply and I don't think I'm done wrong.

Comment: Further research let me found this folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Debugger\WebViews\BptDiagnosticCommon\Icons in my case no .png includes a breakpoint icon but I don't know it this is the right place to search...

Comment: Searching trough my Windows (which probably creates this problem) I found several things. In C:\Windows\WinSxS\ theres a folder called amd64_microsoft-windows-m..oolsclient.appxmain_" and some numbers. Nevertheless is uses the explorere search for "breakpoints" and I found an breakpoints.css . This file is nearly empty (only the line: "DCH,îB  
 "). Searching trough my Laptop I found the same file, but this time about 332 lines long, but my system blocks a replace or copy of this file. I also searched for the breakpoint and I found some png but I dont know where they located.

Comment: Another information: I can set bookmarks etc. (except breakpoints) in the indication margin, and they all have symbols/icons.

Comment: One more information: Installing VS on a new setup Win 10 on the same pc but only another ssd without connectiong my other 3 ssds workes. I looks like I have to resetup my pc :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
(System: Win-10)
(VisualStudioversion: 17/19)

1. Check if there is a breakpoint.png on your computer (if this is missing, this solution wont work). (Search in Windows explorer and enable to see all file and search trough everything filename, file etc. [enable this in the settings])
2. Create Win10 .iso with the offered tool from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10) and store it on the desktop.
3. Execute this .iso and press install Windows. [Dont forget to cross the right checkbox to keep your data and just replace all your windows files]
   !Some settings will be gone after new installation as they inherited by the system! (but most things will stay)
4. After finishing the (re)installation just start vs 17/19 and the Breakpoint should work now or better should be visible breakpoints. :D

Note: I tried a lot of things including a huge amount of testing, checking etc.. This solution should work, but there is the possibility, that I fixed the issue with some other test or stuff I've done. Though there is no guarantee that this will work, but if it doesn't work, just leave a comment and I can try to remember what I've done along my solution process.